# Disable QGraphicsScene autoscale

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have a scene where I paint a series of items using a drag-and-drop process. What I want to do is to place the item where I loose it, do not auto-scale it. What happens to me is that if for example, having the scene empty, I drag an item and release it very close to the right side of the scene, it puts me in the middle and that's not what I want. What I want is to put it where I let it go and if the item does not enter the horizontal axis the horizontal scroll appears so that the user can see it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only geometry matter,

To disable auto scale you need to fixed the size of your scene http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop

You need to check the mouse position on your item and over your scene to place it, and after that, check the frame of your item and if it does not enter the horizontal axis, resize your scene.

see the draggableicons Qt example for the position, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-draganddrop-draggableicons-example.html, and after that, try to resize your scene if it doesn't fit